# R Shiny dynamic list variable to multiple rows

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a sidebar that outputs the columns of a datatable  and the number of unique values in each column. The code below works for the names but when it comes to the unique values I can only get it to display if the list variable is unlist()ed. I could not find any articles that talk about getting a textOutput or equivalent that would handle a list variable across multiple rows.

```
library(shiny)

data(mtcars)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, checkboxGroupInput("dsnamesGrp","Variable name")),
          column(6, uiOutput("dsordsGrp"), inline= FALSE)
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput('contents'))
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({mtcars})
    dsnames <- list()
    dsnames <- names(mtcars)
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dsnamesGrp",
                             label = "Column name",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
    ord_values <- list()
    ord_values <- lapply(mtcars, function(x)length(unique(x)))
    output$dsordsGrp <- renderText({unlist(ord_values)})
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `lengths` on the `unique` elements on the `list`

```
ord_values <- lengths(lapply(mtcars, unique))
output$dsordsGrp <- renderText({ord_values})
```

---

-full code

```
library(shiny)

data(mtcars)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, checkboxGroupInput("dsnamesGrp","Variable name")),
          column(6, htmlOutput("dsordsGrp"), inline= FALSE)
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput('contents'))
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({mtcars})
     dsnames <- names(mtcars)
     cb_options <- list()
     cb_options[dsnames] <- dsnames
     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dsnamesGrp",
                             label = "Column name",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")

    output$dsordsGrp <- renderUI({
          HTML(paste(lengths(lapply(mtcars, unique)), collapse="<br/>"))

})
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Or if we are using the same code as in the OP, instead of `lapply` (always returns a `list` output) use `sapply` which returns a `vector` because the default argument is `simplify = TRUE` and with that it uses the `simplify2array`

```
ord_values <- sapply(mtcars, function(x)length(unique(x)))
output$dsordsGrp <- renderText({ord_values})
```

EDIT: changed `renderText` to `renderUI`

Comment: Both your modified lengths to lapply and sapply forms result in the same output as I get now. I still see the second column as a string of entries (25 3 27 22 22 29 30 2 2 3 6) and not separated into rows. Do you know how to get the data to output as separate rows aligned the column of names?

Comment: @terrangreen  I thought your question was how to remove that `unlist` part?  If you want to separate this into rows, use `cat`

Comment: Okay, cat gets the desired result in the console. I still need to have the list variable (or vector, if that is better) to display across multiple rows in the ui.

Comment: @terrangreen  You can use `column(6, htmlOutput("dsordsGrp"), inline= FALSE)` and `output$dsordsGrp <- renderUI({
              HTML(paste(lengths(lapply(mtcars, unique)), collapse="<br/>"))
    
    })`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Any chance you would be able to get the rows to align with checkboxGroupInput?